"Invalid module format" when running a cross-compiled linux kernel module
I'm trying to cross compile the ad7192 linux driver for a raspberry pi 4 running the latest 64 bit raspberry pi OS(kernel 6.6.20).
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64 GNU/Linux

For this I have referred this documentation form raspberry pi website: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html
I was able to successfully cross compile the drivers and get the ad7192.ko and ad_sigma_delta.ko files. But when trying to load these modules in my raspberry pi 4, I get below error:
sudo insmod ./ad7192.ko 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./ad7192.ko: Invalid module format

dmesg output:
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects$ dmesg | tail
[    8.968011] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[    9.023233] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[   10.132640] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII (RX delay)
[   10.137586] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[   10.155113] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[   13.602651] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.602681] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.602699] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  168.501984] ad_sigma_delta: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 1188.159614] ad7192: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

modinfo of cross compiled kernel module:
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects$ modinfo ./ad7192.ko 
filename:       /home/pi/projects/./ad7192.ko
import_ns:      IIO_AD_SIGMA_DELTA
license:        GPL v2
description:    Analog Devices AD7190, AD7192, AD7193, AD7195 ADC
author:         Michael Hennerich <michael.hennerich@analog.com>
srcversion:     20706613A2C0E80760EE23E
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7195C*
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7195
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7193C*
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7193
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7192C*
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7192
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7190C*
alias:          of:N*T*Cadi,ad7190
alias:          spi:ad7195
alias:          spi:ad7193
alias:          spi:ad7192
alias:          spi:ad7190
depends:        ad_sigma_delta,industrialio
intree:         Y
name:           ad7192
vermagic:       6.6.20-v8 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions aarch64

I have tried to build the kernel module against raspberry pi linux kernel versions 6.6.y and 6.6.20(using exact commit id). But I get the same error in both the linux sources.(https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux)
Can someone please tell me why am I not able to load the modules even though I'm using the exact same kernel source version and architecture?
